# OrientDB ORM framework or Graphical framework

Tags: orm, spring-data, orientdb, graph-databases

I am currently working on a project where i need to model my data as a graphical map using orient DB, I need to know if there is any well tested and dependable framework that can help me, either (preferred) as graphical or as ORM i read that there is some spring implementation (spring data) but yet cannot find any helpful resources.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [OrientDB Spring Data](https://github.com/orientechnologies/spring-data-orientdb/tree/develop) module?

Comment: I have searched for an appropriate tutorial for it, but cannot find one. (i couldn't find how to add dependencies on maven)